# How to deploy frontend and backend with the same domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns

I'm not very familiar with deployment and networking as I'm primarily a frontend developer. I want to create a project with Laravel and React (separated, not integrated with blade), and deploy them to AWS. I want to use Laravel only as an API server, and I'm planning to deploy it on EC2. If I host my React app on S3, how will it be possible for me to share the same domain with the API sever running on the EC2 instance?

I know that I can have separate subdomains,like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) for my React app and api.example.com for my API server. However, if I want to have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) for my React app and [www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api) for my API server, what options do I have? And what resources can you recommend for me to get more up to speed on this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you want to use S3 and EC2 you would need to use a service that can distribute to both endpoints based on a condition.

The best service for this would be [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), which supports distribution to S3 and EC2 (as a [custom origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html)).

To do this you would create your distribution with an [origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Origin.html) for the S3 bucket, and an origin for the API. As your API is hosted on the `/api/*` path you would add this as the [path pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern) when adding the secondary origin via a [behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CacheBehavior.html).

CloudFront will then route any requests to `/api/*` paths to your EC2 origin.

I have found an article named [How to route to multiple origins with CloudFront](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-route-to-multiple-origins-with-cloudfront/) which I hope will explain the steps to accomplish this in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Your response was very helpful, I read the article that you linked, and I'll look more into how CloudFront would be able to help me with what I need. Thanks again! :)